# arrange data based on user defined variables order?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have the following `data.frame` and would like to change the order of the rows in such a way that rows with `variable == "C"` come at the top followed by rows with "A" and then those with "B".

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
D1 <- data.frame(Serial = 1:10, A= runif(10,1,5),
                 B = runif(10,3,6),
                 C = runif(10,2,5)) %>% 
     pivot_longer(-Serial, names_to = "variables", values_to = "Value" ) %>% 
  arrange(-desc(variables))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D1 %>%
   mutate(variables = ordered(variables, c('C', 'A', 'B'))) %>%
   arrange(variables)
```

Perhaps I did not get the question. If you want C then A then B, you could do:

```
D1 %>%
   arrange(Serial, variables)
```

Comment: nice. You don't actually need `ordered`, `factor` will do.

Comment: Thanks Onyambu, your answer did help solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Onyambu's answer is probably the most "tidyverse-ish" way to do it, but another is:

```r
D1[order(match(D1$variables,c("C","A","B"))),]
```

or

```r
D1 %>% slice(order(match(variables,c("C","A","B"))))
```

or

```r
D1 %>% slice(variables %>% match(c("C","A","B")) %>% order())
```

Comment: Thank you Ben for suggesting another possible solution.

Comment: @akrun, don't know. Maybe someone's having a bad day. I suspect this is a dupe, but didn't have the energy to look very hard/figure out a search strategy. Any ideas?